# indexOf troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, indexof

How come this part returns a result:

```
var s = "foo";
alert(s.indexOf("oo") > -1);
```

But this part doesn't:

```
var currentLocation = window.location;
alert(currentLocation.indexOf(".") > -1);
```

Comment: Because `window.location` is not a string or an array, it's a [Location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location), try with `window.location.toString()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am not sure how this works in terms of giving marks for right answer. Unless mpcabd protest I'm gonna give it to Scimonster

Comment: I don't mind that, I'll even up-vote his answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `window.locaton` isn't a string. It's an object with [several properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location).

You can check `window.location.href` for the entire URL (guaranteed to contain a dot), or `window.location.pathname` for just the path (after the domain).

Comment: To forestall any accusations of taking the solution from another user's comment, i wrote this before he posted the comment, but couldn't post it due to losing an internet connection.

Comment: Don't worry Man :) We're all here to help.

Comment: @mpcabd Thanks for that. I did that because a different time i actually did get downvotes and a plagiarism accusation.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.toString()`

```
var currentLocation = window.location.toString();
alert(currentLocation.indexOf("."));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/ufrgzszx/)**

To see all properties

```
showLoc();
function showLoc() {
  var oLocation = window.location, aLog = ["Property (Typeof): Value", "window.location (" + (typeof oLocation) + "): " + oLocation ];
  for (var sProp in oLocation){
    aLog.push(sProp + " (" + (typeof oLocation[sProp]) + "): " +  (oLocation[sProp] || "n/a"));
  }
  alert(aLog.join("\n"));
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/82y6L8v1/)**